# ASP.NET MVC Route parameter separate by ":" char

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Now I am not sure it practical or not but I like to have a URL like this

`http://example.com/field1_query:field2_query` map but it seem like ASP.NET MVC Routing not happy with the ":" char here my route

```
routes.MapRoute("filter", 
      "{field1_query}:{field2_query}", 
      new { controller ="...", action="..."} );
```

It doesn't work but if I change to `{field1_query}/{field2_query}` it works fine (which mean my URL also change `http://example.com/field1_query/field2_query`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colon is a reserved character in a URL. See the [IETF](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) spec.  You would need to escape any restricted or reserved characters.